# Is Next.js app an SPA or single page application?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Plain React apps are called SPA because they have only one html page which is the index.html. But that is not the case for next.js. So can we call a next.js app a single page application?

Answer (score 6):

Good question.

Normally we don't call an engine *SPA* or not. For instance, *React* can do *SPA*, but it can do non-SPA work as well. The same applies to the *NextJS* as well.

Just to follow your dictionary. *NextJS* by default is not *SPA* based due to its hybrid nature, because it publishes each page as a separate entry point for everything under `/pages`. Of course if you only have one page `index.js`, then technically it's a *SPA* again. I guess it depends on how you structure your pages.

Comment: Does that mean if we are statically generating multiple pages we can't call it SPA? And how can we make a non-spa application with react? As far I know we can only make another div the parent with portals except for the div with id root. But how can we insert react components in another html file except for the index.html(default) file?

Comment: nextJS only support a special case to statically back the html pages, but even if you statically generates it, it's still a  SPA :) Anyway, if you need to insert react multiple times to another html, just do `ReactDOM.render` multiple times.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, we can call nextjs a SPA even if you create many pages, but to keep it as such you should use client side transitions (no `<a>` tag).

First of all, SPA = Single Page Application

I assume the question intend SPA vs MPA (Multi Page Application)
The answer is Nextjs can do both depending if you use next link
https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next/link

That will perform a client side transition without reloading the page from the server, assuming your page is static of coure and does not use getServerSideProps(). You can check that by watching the Network in Chrome debug tools.
How that works ? On first page load, all pages get loaded in js inside the vdom and any page can get injected into your browser dom fromthe client js not from the server.

To give it an MPA behavior, you can also link a relative page with a simple html anchor tag `<a>`, that will reload the page from the server, as the a tag uses no js for that. What could be the advantage of that ? keeping code clean from next maybe, and if you mess the react vdom (which you shouldn't) you're sure to get a fresh page again. A disadvantage of that is that you loaded all content in js initialy anyway, so reloading with anchors is a waste of resources and load time.

Note using PWA (Progressive Web App) is also an option to optimise the user experience, and it is also supported by nextjs
see
https://nextjs.org/docs/faq
and
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/progressive-web-app